# How to add a period at end of print

Tags: python

Basic stuff, I am getting a syntax error for this. How do I include a period at the end of the printed line?

```
first_name = raw_input("Enter your first name: ")
last_name = raw_input("Enter your last name: ")
print "Enter your date of birth" 
month= raw_input("Month? ")
day= raw_input("Day? ")
year= raw_input("Year? ")

print "Here's your information"
print first_name, "was born on", month, day+',', year.
```

Comment: Like the same way you used `,` in `day+','`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to concatenate it:

```
print first_name, "was born on", month, day+',', year, "."
```

UPDATE: as @sr2222 points out, this will print an extra space before the period. If you want to avoid it (and assuming that year is a string):

```
print first_name, "was born on", month, day+',', year + "."
```

Comment: That's going to put a space between `year` and the period.

Comment: Fixed it, print first_name, "was born on", month, day+',', year+"."

Comment: Yes, but since he was using commas in all the statement, I decided to follow his example.

Comment: He wasn't though.  Look between `day` and `','`.

Comment: @sr2222 True enough, didn't see that. I updated my answer to refer to your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Put quotation marks around it.

```
print first_name, "was born on", month, day+',', year +'.'
```

Though really, you should clean this up, as combining a bunch of different string concatenation mechanisms in a single line gets hard to read.

```
print first_name + " was born on " + month + ", " + day + ", " + year + "."
```

There is also [the big wide world of string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples), of course.

Comment: Silas, I tried using your method with the + but I get an error.

Comment: What error?  And are you using Python 3 by any chance?

Comment: Silas, yes I am using python 3. The error given is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.